# Restore RAID 0 storage volume after Windows 7 re-install?

Tags: windows-7, software-raid, raid-0

I have a RAID 0 storage volume in Windows 7 with 3 disks and I want to re-install Windows to the OS drive. If I do this, will Windows recognize the previous RAID array and configure appropriately?

Note 1: Windows is not installed to the RAID.

Note 2: The RAID is a Windows RAID, not a device RAID.

Comment: The RAID to Windows looks as an installation destination.  It will do exactly what it did when you originally installed the operating system.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows will install to the OS disk it is currently installed to, not the RAID. I have no idea what you're talling about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the answer is "yes", it has nothing to do with appropriate drivers (since this is a Windows RAID). In Disk Management, the drives will appear as 'Dymamic', but unusable. Right-clicking one of the drives and selecting an option, I believe it was something along the lines of 'Create dynamic volumes', allows restoration of the drive volume. This worked on my RAID 0 with 3 disks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: YES

Longer version: The data in RAID 0 has nothing to do with your Windows 7 system. As long as your Windows is equipped with proper RAID driver, your raid drive is nothing different from a legacy HDD.

Comment: It is a Windows RAID. Does the same apply?

Comment: I guess you can report a bug to Microsoft if it didn't work. Check [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a86c60db-3f1c-4426-a831-ab7260ce8346/recover-software-raid5-volume-after-reinstalling-windows-server-2012?forum=winserver8gen) for more reassurance.